# Liferay Grails portlet taglib issue

Tags: grails, liferay, taglib

I am using Liferay 6.0.6 and have successfully created a test portlet using the Grails Liferay Portlets Plugin.  I am now trying to use some of the Liferay taglibs so my portlet will have the same look and feel as other portlets. My problem now is I can't get any of the liferay-ui controls to render. Should I be able to use the Liferay taglibs from Grails?  I have inspected the war file for my portlet and all the Liferay taglibs and jar files seem to be in the right places.  Can someone point me in the right direction?